# Borrar TODOS los nodos hijos de un div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación y me he encontrado con la siguiente problemática:

- Al pulsar el botón "Analizar" creo dinámicamente con JavaScript distintos `div` que contienen su propia tabla con datos. La problemática me surge que al pulsar el mismo botón una segunda vez me "duplica" los datos de las tablas.
- Para evitar el problema antes de la creación de los `div` compruebo si están creados o no, y si existen borro todos los elementos que contiene ("hijos") con el fin de volverlos a crear pero con la información actualizada.
- La cosa es que consigo que no me salgan los `div` duplicados, pero dentro de estos la información de la tabla sí que se me duplica y no encuentro la forma de evitarlo.

[image]

Dejo el HTML inicial (en el div "background" es donde se insertan los nuevos `div` con sus tablas):

```js
function GetInformation() {
  var section = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "F"];
  var div = document.getElementById("top-mail-box");

  //<---------- Compruebo si existen los div --------->

  if (div != null) {
    var parent = div.parentElement;
    parent.removeChild(div);
  } else {
    alert("No existe la caja previamente creada.");
  }


  //<---------- Resto del código que me inserta los datos de las tablas --------->
  $.ajax({
    url: '../GetInformation',
    type: 'GET',
    datatype: 'text',
    success: function(json) {

      var content = document.createElement("div");
      content.className = "top-mail-box";
      content.id = "top-mail-box";
      document.getElementById("background").appendChild(content);

      for (i = 0; i < section.length; i++) {

        //SECTION (creación de los distintos Div)

        var meanDiv = document.createElement("div");
        meanDiv.className = "accordion-group";
        meanDiv.id = "meanDiv";
        var firstDiv = document.createElement("div");
        firstDiv.className = "accordion-heading";

        var firstA = "<a class='section_title'>" + section[i] + "</a>";
        var secondA = "<a class='section_icon' data-toggle='collapse' onclick='Section(" + "\"" + section[i] + "\"" + ")'>" +
          "<i id ='" + section[i] + "-icon' class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down'>" + "</i>" +
          "</a >";
        firstDiv.innerHTML = firstA + secondA;

        var secondDiv = document.createElement("div");
        secondDiv.className = "accordion-body collapse";
        secondDiv.id = section[i];
        var internalsecondDiv = document.createElement("div");
        internalsecondDiv.className = "accordion-inner";

        var tablesecondDiv = document.createElement("table");
        tablesecondDiv.className = "table table - striped table - condensed";
        tablesecondDiv.id = section[i] + "table";

        internalsecondDiv.appendChild(tablesecondDiv);
        secondDiv.appendChild(internalsecondDiv);

        meanDiv.appendChild(firstDiv);
        meanDiv.appendChild(secondDiv);

        document.getElementById("top-mail-box").appendChild(meanDiv);

        //THEAD (creación del encabezado de las tablas)

        var theadElement = document.createElement("thead");
        var trElement = document.createElement("tr");
        trElement.className = "columns";
        var row = "<th>Category</th><th>Key</th><th>Value</th><th>Description</th>";
        trElement.innerHTML = row;
        theadElement.appendChild(trElement);
        document.getElementById(section[i] + "table").appendChild(theadElement);

        //TBODY (inserción de los datos en cada tabla)

        var tbodyElement = document.createElement("tbody");

        for (j = 0; j < json.length; j++) {
          if (json[j].ConfigFile == files[i]) {
            var trElementBody = document.createElement("tr");
            trElementBody.id = "row";
            var tdElement = "<td>" + json[j].Category + "</td><td>" + json[j].Key + "</td><td>" + json[j].Value + "</td><td>" + json[j].Description + "</td>";
            trElementBody.innerHTML = tdElement;
            tbodyElement.appendChild(trElementBody);
          }
        }

        document.getElementById(section[i] + "table").appendChild(tbodyElement);
      }
    },
    error: function(xhr, status) {
      alert(xhr + " : " + status);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mail-box">
  <div id="background" class="background">

  </div>
  <div class="pbottom">
    <div class="pull-right">
      <input type="submit" value="Analyse" class="btn btn-primary correct" onclick="GetInformation()" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

También me valdría refrescar la página siempre de forma inicial y luego llamar a la función GetInformation() pero no logro hacer que se ejecute secuencialmente.

Comment: Si el div con id `background` siempre tendrá un div `top-mail-box`, cambia `parent.removeChild(div);` por `div.innerHTML = "";`.

Comment: Mira es una sugerencia nada mas, ya que no se si tendrás el tiempo suficiente para realizar el cambio. Pero podrías agregar un div que sea el contenga  la data que deseas mostrar y que cuando presiones nuevamente el botón borra primero el contenido el div con $.empty() y luego vuelves a crear el contenido . Espero haberme explicado .

Comment: no entendí tu problemática, dices que quieres eliminar el `div` contenedor (asumo que es el que tiene la tabla) pero que luego dices que la tabla te sale con datos duplicados, a que te refieres con datos duplicados, ¿te sale una tabla con doble cantidad de filas y datos duplicados?¿te sale dos veces la tabla?¿te aparece el contenido de cada celda duplicado?¿la tabla esta dentro del `div` que estas eliminándole el contenido? creo que se necesita una aclaración a tu problema

Comment: "La problemática me surge que al pulsar el mismo botón una segunda vez me "duplica" los datos de las tablas." La idea es que cuando pulse el botón una segunda vez me elimine los divs y las tablas creadas y me los inserte de nuevo con los datos actualizados. La cosa es que los datos contenidos en las tablas no se borran y entonces los nuevos se me insertan a continuación de los que había. Espero que ahora se haya entendido mejor.

Comment: El Stack Snippet no es ejecutable por lo que no se puede reproducir el problema. Posiblemente falla por el uso de referencias relativas en el ajax.

Answer (score 1):

puede utilizar la propiedad de reemplazar, que me permiter reemplazar si encuentra un div que ya esta definido y evitar el duplicador, aqui le dejor un ejemplo

```
<p id="demo">Visit Microsoft!</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
    var res = str.replace("Microsoft", "W3Schools");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Gracias @marcos alberto saavedra sanabr pero no es lo que estoy buscando, de esta manera tendría que sustituir 1 a 1 cada fila de cada tabla, además que no aseguro que en la "actualización" se mantenga el número de filas... aumentando la problemática.

Answer (score 0):

si estas usando jquery por que no haces esto

```js
var div = $("#top-mail-box");

  if (div.length > 0) {
    div.find(".accordion-group").remove();
  } else {
    alert("No existe la caja previamente creada.");
  }
```

Recuperas el contenedor y cuando lo hace, encuentra los hijos con x nombre y despues los eliminas o si solo es esa la información que tienes puedes hacer

```
$("#top-mail-box").html("");
```

y así eliminas toda la información de es

Comment: Hola @Leonidas Segura, gracias por intentar resolverme el problema pero me sigue haciendo lo mismo, me borra los div pero me mantiene la información de las tablas por lo que los datos me salen duplicados.

Answer (score -1):

**Edit**
En la foto que incluyes hay muchas `div` con el mismo `ID`, sin ver el código generado es difícil saber con precisión, pero seguramente haya una sola de las `div`s que se comporta bien y el resto queda igual.

los ID de elementos deben ser todos diferentes, prueba agregarle el indice del elemento como parte del nombre (por ejemplo: `id="MeanDiv-1"`, `id="AMI-1"`, `id="AMITable-1"`... , `id="MeanDiv-2"` etc...), o usar un atributo `data-id` para identificarla y cambiarle el contenido en vez de borrarla.

**original**
Para Borrar hijos con un solo nivel de anidamiento yo uso este snipet

```
while (element.firstChild){
  element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
};
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

para mas niveles habría que hacerlo recursivo como en esta respuesta 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32261977/1423096

**nota** la recursividad sólo es necesaria si los elementos son muy pesados en memoria y no se quiere esperar que el recolector de basura elimine los "nietos y sus descendientes" al no encontrar referencias.

Comment: Hola @alo Malbarez, gracias por intentar resolverme el problema pero me sigue haciendo lo mismo, me borra los div pero me mantiene la información de las tablas por lo que los datos me salen duplicados